# how to capture mouse cursor in screen grab?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, graphics, macos-carbon

I'm using OpenGL to grab the contents of the Mac OSX screen - thsi works very well, except it does not grab the mouse cursor graphic. I need to somewhow get that cursor graphic, either as part of my screen capture routine, or separately.

My question is either:

- How can I ensure that the mouse cursor image is included with the OpenGL screen grab?

or

- How can I get the current mouse cursor image as a simple RGBA bitmap?

I'm developing under Mac OSX 10.6, using C++ / Carbon.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use I/O Kit to read the pixels for the current cursor. See [IOFramebufferShared.h](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/KernelIOKitFramework/IOFramebufferShared_h/) and [IOGraphicsLib.h](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/IOKit/IOGraphicsLib_h/) for some of the relevant API.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - that looks dreadfully complex though - I don't suppose you have some sample code that shows how to do it? The best I can find using google is something like:

http://orange.kame.net/dev/cvsweb.cgi/xfree86/xc/programs/Xserver/hw/darwin/Attic/xfIOKit.c?rev=1.1&cvsroot=apps

which isn't exactly easy to understand...

Comment: This should get you started: https://bitbucket.org/boredzo/mouseflashlight/src/tip/NSCursor+PRHCurrentGlobalCursor.h https://bitbucket.org/boredzo/mouseflashlight/src/tip/NSCursor+PRHCurrentGlobalCursor.m The missing piece is that it doesn't actually copy the pixels; for that app, just the size and hot spot were enough.

Comment: Hi Peter,

Can u provide some sample code for capture mouse cursor with screen